# не устанавливается pyinstaller (xxxxx)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Хотел установить pyinstaller, но выдает ошибку.

Устанавливал как на последней версии пипа 20.3.3, так и на 18.1,запускал cmd от имени администратора, но все безуспешно...

Ошибка:

```
  Collecting pyinstaller
    Using cached pyinstaller-4.1.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
    Installing build dependencies ... done
    Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\гыук\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\гыук\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\110E~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwulj1830'
         cwd: C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s5gxfqbk\pyinstaller_620ecbb9c5984af9a2d5e1b11486ece3
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\гыук\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xuuhzg21\pyinstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\гыук\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\гыук\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\110E~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwulj1830' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: как устанавливаете pyinstaller?

Answer (score 0):

Ваша версия Python не подходит к pyinstaller
Установите версию Python 3.8
если будет возникать еще ошибка желтым цветом обновите pip инструкции есть в интернете, также попробуйте обновить pip до самой новой версии командой cd (и путь к директории корневых файлов Python) а после командой
python -m pip install --upgrade pip обновите pip

Comment: Версия питона 3.8

Comment: пробовал как на последней версии пипа так и 18.1 ( как рекомендовали в интернете) ничего не помогло.

Comment: а каким цветом подсвечивало ошибку? и какая у вас операционная система?

Comment: windows 10, красная

Comment: у меня возникала подобная ошибка но обновлением все решилось в вашем случае я даже не знаю что делать

Comment: @Иван Попробуйте еще установить(переустановить)  wheel. `pip install wheel`